# Double nested parentheses throw an error inside macro when using the defined operator

Tags: c, macros, defined

I am writing an emulator and I want it to be exactly like macros in C. The following code confuses me:

This is valid code and returns true:

```
#if ((((1 + ((2)))))) == 3
```

This is also valid code and returns true:

```
#define hi hello
#if defined (hi)
```

But this will throw an error and not compile:

```
#define hi hello
#if defined ((hi))
```

Is there a special reason why this does not work?
It seems like it should work.

Here is a link if you want to test macros online: https://godbolt.org/ (put -E as argument)
Here a link that explains the defined operator: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.4.0/cpp/Defined.html

Comment: I don't think `#ifdef (hi)` is valid. The [specification](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.1p5) says that `#ifdef` must be followed by an identifier, not an expression.

Comment: The parameter to `defined()` has to be an identifier, not an expression.

Comment: but if you look at the second link, which is from gcc.gnu.org, they even show it as an example with (), also it works on 3 different compilers i tried

Comment: `defined()` allows parentheses, `#ifdef` doesn't. If it's accepted, it's an extension by those compilers.

Comment: Apparently [C11 6.10.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.1) does not accept `#if defined ( ( whatever ) )`

Comment: ok sorry this was my mistake, i edited the question, parentheses dont work with ifdef and single parentheses work with defined but not double

Comment: _"This is valid code and returns true:"_ `#if ((((1 + ((2)))))) == 3`.  My compiler does not agree:  `error: unterminated conditional directive`
`

Comment: ryyker i just tested  `#if ((((1 + ((2)))))) == 3`  again and i am sure it works for me, maybe it doesnt work on all compilers, but i think it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#if` does a *mathematical* evaluation. Your parenthesis get evaluated as in a C expression. The more the merrier, they don't change the value the expression evaluates *to* (except when they do, of course, when set to change operator precedence).

`#ifdef identifier` / `#if defined identifier` / `#if defined( identifier )` (the parenthesis are optional for the `defined` operator, and not allowed for `#ifdef`) checks if the given *identifier* is defined. An identifier begins with a letter or an underscore, and contains only letters, underscores, or digits.

`hi` is an identifier.

`(hi)` is not.

Comment: Oh i think defined() can be seen like a function call, this is why single parentheses work but double do not? It would be like a function that could be used with parentheses or without

Comment: @Alexanus: No. The preprocessor has its own set of rules (which I had to look up myself to be sure, hence the flurry of edits...). The parenthesis are optional in `#if defined()` (6.10.1 (1)), and not allowed in `#ifdef` (6.10.1 (5)).

Answer (score 1):

C 2018 6.10.1 specifies the behavior of `define` in a `#if` or `#elif` directive. It says the expression that controls conditional inclusion:

> … may contain unary operator expressions of the form
>
> `defined` *identifier*
>
> or
>
> `defined` `(` *identifier* `)`
>
> which evaluate to 1 if the identifier is currently defined as a macro
> name…

Thus, the operand of `defined` is not a general C expression but is **only** “*identifier*” or “`(` *identifier* `)`”.